# Where can I search for my favorite questions?

Tags: support

There was a star button for each question which says "This is a favorite question", I wonder where I can find all the qustions I've ever tagged as favorite? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a *Favorites* tab on your main profile next to *Badges*. Here is [yours](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/696/leon-cheung?tab=favorites).

Comment: Ah, there it is, never noticed it, thanks!